# How to redirect request to another application node using mod jk during 503 from one node in cluster?

Tags: apache, cluster-computing, mod-jk

My application is running on clustering environment.I have two Apache server connected with 4 Jboss Application node.When one of the application node becomes unresponsive Apache throwing 503.
In this case i want to redirect the same request to another application node so that end user will not face 503 issue.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is achieved using parameter `lb_retries` in the `load_balancer` configuration.

According to documentation in http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html:

> When making a request, the load-balancer worker will allocate the request to a member worker. If that member worker is either unable to service the request or fails to service the request, the request will be passed to another member worker until the request is processed, every member worker has attempted to process the request or lb_retries member workers have attempted to process the request.
>
> If the request remains unprocessed, the load-balancer worker will repeat the above process a maximum of retries times (including the original attempt). Before each retry, the load-balancer worker will pause for a time defined by the retry_interval directive.
>
> Note that this means that, if all workers fail, there will be a total of worker.retries * min(lb.lb_retries,member worker count) * lb.retries requests before a 504 response is returned to the client. So for an lb worker with four members and a default configuration, if all workers fail there will be a total of 8 requests before a 504 response is returned to the client.
>
> This feature has been added in jk 1.2.44. Prior to this feature being added, the load-balancer worker behaved as if lb_retries was equal to the number of member workers.

As stated there `lb_retries` has a default value of `2`.

Be aware of the relationship between `lb_retries` and `retries`, they are tigthly related to each other